# How to integrate PayPal Smart Payment buttons in NuxtJs?

Tags: paypal, nuxt.js

My current working solution.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div ref="paypal"></div>     
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted: function () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=SECRET";
    script.addEventListener("load", this.setLoaded);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  },

  methods: {
    openPaymentAmountModal() {
      this.isPaymentAmountModalVisible = true;
    },
    closePaymentAmountModal() {
      this.isPaymentAmountModalVisible = false;
    },
    setLoaded: function () {
      window.paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
          // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
              amount: {
                value: '0.01'
              }
            }]
          });
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
          // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
          return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
            // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
          });
        }
      }).render(this.$refs.paypal);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In modals, I had to load the script again.

How to load this Paypal script **globally** in the NuxtJs application on components or pages level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same integration in my project, and import the script in my page:

```
head() {
    return {
        script: [{
            src: 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<CLIENT_ID>'
        }],
    }
},
```

Then put PayPal's `.render()` method in the `mounted()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add the script to the head, in the SPA index.htm - this means it will always be available and you do not need to wait for the load.

This means you can call the button creation against a known div element anytime. If it is in a modal, the same would apply, although you might wish to adjust the render target then.

Answer (score 0):

you can also put the script in the script array in nuxt.config.js, by doing this the script is made available globally in your application.
Like this:

```
script: [
      {
        src: 'ttps://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<CLIENT_ID>',
        async: true
      }
    ]
```